# How to style archive post titles... but only those posts who have comments?

Tags: posts, css, comments, title

How would I style archive post titles for only those posts who have comments?

Comment: It's actually the front page/posts page

Answer (score 1):

Use `have_comments()` function.

**Example:**

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

    <h2 class="has-comments"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php else : ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The site does not open... I gave just an example of implementation. Use `have_comments()` function to set class or styles.